# Get elements of a numpy array that satisfy some condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array full of integers, let's say

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I want to get a binary array containing 1 if the element satisfies belongs to a list, and 0 otherwise.

If I write

```
condition = arr == 2
```

I get

```
[[false, true], [false, false]]
```

which is what I want.

But what if I want to keep the elements 2 and 3 ?
I tried

```
condition = arr in [2,3]
```

but it doesn't work, I get a

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

I would like to do that for any possible list.

Is there any efficient way to do that?
I know how to do it brutally, but I'm need to be efficient.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean `arr[(arr == 2) | (arr == 3)]`?

Comment: `condition = arr == 2` returns that: `array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Yes @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, I corrected it thank you.

Comment: @timgeb I want to be able to do it for any list !

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
np.isin(arr,[2,3])
```

output:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!

Comment: @AdrienNivaggioli, have you tried my answer in order to see if it's working ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut of course your solution is working. It is also mentioned in the comments. But I think (with all modesty:) ) that my solution is more elegant, and requires less code, especially if the second list is large.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. :-)

```
arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.logical_or(arr==2,arr==3)
```

output:

```
array([[False,  True],
      [ True, False]])
```